# SQL: select all depending nodes from a list of parent

Tags: sql, postgresql

let's take a table called users like this

| id | name | ... | path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | John | ... | 2/8/11/22/ |
| 23 | Mark | ... | 1/3/9/15/21/23/ |

where the path rapresents the hierarchy parent-child.

Now, I have a list of "special users" which we can call them "board-users" and, for semplicity, let's say they have id 1 to 10.

I would like to select all the rows which derive from the board users (including board users rows itself) and I would like to add a column related to the board users parent; something like this:

| id | name | ... | path | board_parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Stephany | ... | 1/ | 1 |
| 2 | Karl | ... | 2/ | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 83 | Lucy | ... | 4/11/43/51/69/73/83/ | 4 |

I have tried something like

```
SELECT u1.id as board_parent_id, u2.*
FROM USERS AS u1
CROSS JOIN USERS AS u2
WHERE u1.id = '1'
AND u2.path LIKE '%1%'
UNION
SELECT u1.id as board_parent_id, u2.*
FROM USERS AS u1
CROSS JOIN USERS AS u2
WHERE u1.id = '2'
AND u2.path LIKE '%2%'
UNION
...
```

but honestly I believe this is a very stupid way to do this

Comment: The first fragment in path is what you want, right?

Comment: On my phone and in a rush, but look into recursive CTEs... .https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/queries-with.html

Comment: it's not an answer, but maybe you can consider using ltree for hierarchical data: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ltree.html

Comment: @SalmanA it is not always necessary the first. a board users might also be the nth in the path... It means I will be interested of that parth starting from the nth user

Comment: @Andronicus Unfortunately I'm not the one who made the Database and I have no power on changing it

Comment: You want to find the full hierarchy for _one_ user? E.g. given user `4/11/43/51/69/73/83/` you want all users in that path? And in that order?

Comment: @SalmanA No, I have a list of 11 "golden members" and I want the list of users in the hierarchy for all these 11 "golden members". I don't really care what order are they, but I would like to have all the fields plus a field which tells me who's the "golden parent"

Comment: @FabioManniti, help me understand your question better. Can you prepare an SQL fiddle with sample table structure, some dummy data and expected result, like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/418b4/9/0

Comment: Can we assume that a golden member is a row whose `id` = `board_parent_id`? Second question: if A is golden, A is the parent of B, then B is the parent of C, whose `board_parent_id` will C have: A's or B's?

Comment: @RobertSynoradzki There is no board parent id in the data, its a column derived by the query (the OP has a list of ids that are implicitly considered the board parents, either in another table or offline, but not in the users table).

Comment: @RobertSynoradzki as said, there is not a table of golden membrers. There only is a table of users like the one described in the example. Then I have been given a list of 10 members said "golden" and they told me "Can you get me all the users who are in the brench of these 10 golden ones?" So I can put them manually in the query.
To answer to your other question: Golden members are the one in the list. So If A>parent of B > parent of C, C's board_parent_id is A's id

Answer (score 0):

First observation:

- your current query should search for `'%/1/%'` not `'%1%'`
- the latter will match `'63/41/999/'`, when you don't want it to

But that also means that your path should start with `'/'`

- or concat `'/'` to the start in your query

If you know the list of golden id's, then it's just a join?

```
WITH
  golden(id) AS
(
  VALUES
    (1),(2),(3)...,(n)
)
SELECT
  golden.id   AS board_parent_id,
  users.*
FROM
  golden
INNER JOIN
  users
    ON CONCAT('/', user.path) LIKE CONCAT('%/', golden.id, '/%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank to the comments and other answers I finally got my query done.

I post here an example

```
WITH BOARD AS(
   SELECT * FROM users 
   WHERE ID IN ('id_1', 'id_2', 'id_3', 'id_4'...)
)
SELECT BOARD.id AS board_id,
u.*
FROM users AS u 
INNER JOIN BOARD ON u.path LIKE CONCAT('%',BOARD.id.'%')
```

This way, it seems to work the way I wanted

Comment: As per my answer, you have a logical fault. As written, `id_1` will also match `id_6/id_12/id_20/` even though you don't actually want `id_12`. If you search for `/id_1/` that false positive match doesn't occur.

Comment: You are 100% right. I didn't emphasize too much on this because I don't actually have this kind of IDs, but a 16 digits ids, which it's harder to replicate

Comment: Why even allow the possibility when there is a guaranteed way to avoid it.  This is building in technical debt where the failure case can be a silent failure.  Adding in the `/`'s to the join is a trivial fix...